# JavaScript: Syntax error? Is it?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have one very simple Javascript code. The code is to change the source of the image when the page loads. It goes something like this:

```
window.onload = initAll;
function initAll(){
    document.getElementById("imgSlider").src = "menuBack.jpg";
}
```

Now, this works perfectly fine. Look at the code below.

```
window.onload = initAll;
function initAll(){
     var imgSrc = document.getElementById("imgSlider").src
     imgSrc = "menuBack.jpg";

}
```

Shouldn't this code perform as the code above? I guess, it should. Is there something wrong in the lower code? I use Mozilla Firefox(latest version). Could this be the problem of the browser?

Comment: aren't youi missimng a semicolon after .src ?

Comment: @rene: Javascript has "automatic semicolon insertion"

Comment: @MM. that is true, which doesn't mean you should rely on it, but I admit that is not the root cause for the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second piece of code should definitely do something else.

The first part:

```
document.getElementById("imgSlider").src = "menuBack.jpg";
```

means that you store the string `"menuBack.jpg"` into `document.getElementById("imgSlider").src`.

However, the second part:

```
 var imgSrc = document.getElementById("imgSlider").src
 imgSrc = "menuBack.jpg";
```

means that you first store `document.getElementById("imgSlider").src` into `imgSrc`, but then overwrite that by storing `"menuBack.jpg"` into `imgSrc`.
That is something different.

Answer (score 3):

do like

```
var imgSrc = document.getElementById("imgSlider");
imgSrc.src = "menuBack.jpg";
```

You should have the dom element in your variable to apply the value to its attribute. Other ways you just have a string which is not dom element.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = initAll;
function initAll(){
     var img = document.getElementById("imgSlider");
     img.src = "menuBack.jpg";
}
```